# Make Gmail send automatic canned responses for email it gets via POP

Tags: gmail, gmail-canned-response

I have email from my personal domain POP'ed by my Gmail account. It works beautifully, except that it can't seem to do auto-replies.

That means that I can't have an away message when I'm on vacation. And it means I can't create filters using canned responses.

(I know that Canned Responses only apply to new, incoming messages that arrive through SMTP [directly sent to Gmail], not to messages fetched through POP3.)

- How can I make this work within Gmail?
- If I don't have access to mail forwarding on my old account, what other options do I have?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Short answer

Instead of using POP use email forwarding from your other account to be able to use Filters and Canned Responses in Gmail

## Explaination

> it can't seem to do auto-replies

I beg to differ.

Make sure Canned Responses is activated:
[image: Activate canned responses Gmail]

Then you create a filter for emails that are sent to your old email address:

to:(my.old.address@example.com)

EDIT: Note that this will not work for mails fetched through POP3, only for forwarded messages. If your old account has an auto-forwarding feature, that's the way to go. (The other answer here pointed this out.)

You call the filter, say, Old. Then you select a canned response for that filter. Actually, you don't even need to do that. You can autorespond to these emails just the same just by creating a filter for them.

Look at this screenshot:

[image: Gmail canned responses autoresponder]

Comment: I guess that's the best answer. Maybe there's a bug in my gmail account because it won't let me do that, but it seems to work for you and others. Thanks.

Comment: @AndrewWarner Have you actually activated canned responses in your Gmail settings? I have added a picture to show you where to find it. As a last resort you can contact Google to help you out.

Comment: I did, but for some reason it only fires off for emails that are sent directly to my @gmail.com address

Comment: @AndrewWarner Are auto-replies to your other emails sent via gmail or via SMTP of your other mail accounts?

Comment: So glad this still works even today! :)

Answer (score 1):

Canned Responses (as Forwarding and the Vacation Responder) only apply to new, incoming messages that arrive through SMTP (directly send to Gmail), not to messages fetched through POP3.

So I've written an Apps Script that will just work for any incoming mail!
http://www.xpos.nl/xpos/download/gs/canned-response-pop3.gs

Comment: Any updates for the script? I mean, I couldn't make it work. Is it still working today?

Comment: This question now has a bounty - can you update your script (or assert that it should still work)?  Are there other approaches that should work now?